# Duplicate `wand` pure pixel stream SHA-256 checksum calculation w/ `hashlib`

Tags: python, sha256, checksum, hashlib, wand

What I did was, on one hand:

```
import wand                     # user-installed
img = wand.image.Image(filename=f)
print(img.signature)
```

which yields results equivalent to invoking `imagemagick` in the local shell:

```
import subprocess              # builtins
cmd = f'identify -format \'%#\' {f}'
print(str(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True),'utf-8'))
```

and, on the other hand:

```
import hashlib                  # builtins
sha_256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha_256.update(open(f,'rb').read() )
print(sha_256.hexdigest())
```

For a given jpg file, `f`, I get:
`bcabffbb94896989099e5d2c11989468567a5f9ca46f12aecc2448079b6c77cb` in the first case, and
`6964a03b39bd71d8cff04cf075d008a93cd3a4973c95edf1e6cfa8c1f5eeb3e0` in the second case.

I suspect that it is because the second method, with `hashlib`, may scoop in more to the image file than just its "clean" pixel stream, perhaps some file metadata, etc.  `wand` does not as it relies only on the pixel stream.

I'd like to reproduce the `wand` result with `hashlib` for Python 3.9.0, but did not get very far on the documentation.  Any pointers anyone?

Comment: The difference is in more than just the presence or absence of metadata: your attempt is hashing the compressed data in the file, ImageMagick is hashing decompressed pixel data.  So you'd still need some sort of image-reading module, to decompress the file data.  And since you're dealing with JPEG, which uses lossy compression, I don't think it would be reasonable to expect that a different module would produce bit-for-bit identical decompressed data (some math operation might be rounded off differently, for example).